# Spring boot Redis @Cacheable method not getting called from another class

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis

May be the questions seems to be duplicate of others but i have already checked other similar questions and tried solutions but nothing worked.

I am having a Service class annotated with cache annotations as follows:

```
@Service
@CacheConfig(cacheNames={"ReqCache"})
public class ReqCache implements CacheFacade{

    @Autowired
   RequestRepository requestRepo;

    @Cacheable
    public Request getRequest(String sessionId) {
        System.out.println("in cache comp");


        return requestRepo.get(sessionId);
        }

@CachePut(value = "ReqCache", key = "#p0.sessionId")
    public void addRequest(Request request, int partition) {
        requestRepo.add(lterequest,partition);
    }
}
```

I am autowiring CacheFacade in another service class.
When i call addRequest from that class it works but when i call getRequest  its not getting called, i tried adding logger and debug point there but the flow doesn't go there.

This is my main service class which calls cache service class:

```
@Service
public class RequestHandler {


@Autowired
    CacheFacade cacheFac;
    }
```

Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong and why @cacheput works but @cacheable method doesn't get called.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try `@Cacheable(value = "ReqCache")`?

Comment: What about the result then, is it correct, is there any exception?

Comment: In Springboot, the `@Cacheable` annotation tells spring to cache those results (only if the annotated method is the first to be called in that service)... I'm assuming it's not allowing you to debug there because it's reading the cached result? It caches the returned value, not the whole function

Comment: @michael  yes i tried that as well..but didnt work

Comment: @shadow it just gives null...even when db has the result

Answer (score 1):

In Springboot, the **@Cacheable** annotation tells spring to cache those results (this works through proxying, so if you want to read the cached results, the method annotated with @Cacheable needs to be the first method called in your service)... I'm assuming it's not allowing you to debug there because it's reading the cached result? It caches the returned value, not the whole function.

So in this example, the first time this method is called with "Jim", it will print Jim, do the db lookup, and return 5. But after that spring remembers that "Jim" was already a parameter for this method, so instead of executing the whole method again, spring knows that "Jim" returns 5. It will execute the whole method again after the cache has been evicted

```
@Cacheable
private int method1(String name){
     System.out.println(name);

     //db lookup
     return repo.getId(name);
}
```

Comment: thanks for ans but it should atleast return some result from db...it always returns null

Comment: Thanks man! It really just needs to be the first method called. Otherwise the cachable is simply ignored.